# Why does my plugin require a permalink reset after a new installation?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, installation

I've searched the site, but can not find anything specifically answering this question, so please point me to the right answer if this is a duplicate.

I have a plugin, and it seems that on any new client installation (I cannot replicate this locally in a dev environment), I am constantly getting support emails asking why the permalinks are 404ing. I respond with "reset your permalinks" and the issue seems to be resolved.

My plugin uses custom post types, everything seems to registered properly (tables, unique function names, etc). No PHP errors are thrown.

So my question boils down to this: why in the world does the custom post type require a permalink reset?

Comment: Have a read through [`flush_rewrite_rules`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules).

Comment: As Milo implied you should `flush_rewrite_rules` on plugin activation after creating your custom post type. Read the doc to understand why.